# Put my labels in front of the graph without obscuring the points

Tags: css, highcharts

I'm using plotbands to label areas on my graph, but since I don't want them to be colored in I have them set to a transparency of 0.  However, I seem to be stuck with two options:  Put them in front of everything, in which case I can't hover over the points to get the tooltips to show, or behind everything in which case the text becomes reddish from the coloring of the area graph.  I set my tooltip zIndex very high with no result.

[image]

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            plotBands: [{
            {
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                from: new Date(2001, 1, 3).getTime(),
                to: new Date(2009, 1, 21).getTime(),
                zIndex: 2,
                label: {
                    text: "Low zIndex, label is reddish",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    y: bandLabelVertOffset,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: bandLabelFontSize,
                        lineHeight: bandLabelLineSpacing,
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                from: new Date(2009, 1, 21).getTime(),
                to: new Date(2013, 0, 0).getTime(),
                zIndex: 20,
                label: {
                    text: "High zIndex, can't click points",
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    y: bandLabelVertOffset,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: bandLabelFontSize,
                        lineHeight: bandLabelLineSpacing,
                        color: 'black',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    }
                }
            }],

    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true,
        zIndex: 4000,
    },
```

Comment: If there's a better way to add the labels than by using plotBands, I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Or is there a way to directly set the zIndex of the points?

Comment: You can add by [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) and [labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels)

Comment: You're basically asking how to put the labels in front without putting them in front...  I would suggest setting the label position to be either above or below the plot area, so that their interaction with the plot does not exist in the first place (or extend your y axis enough to allow the label to be in the plot area while being clear of the series).

Comment: I want labels in front of the plot area, not in front of the points.  Being able to directly set the zIndex on the points would solve my problem, as would being able to use labels separate from plotbands.  @SebastianBochan's solution looks promising; I'm working on it now.

Comment: You can use `pointer-events: none` for the high z-index labels for the points to be clickable. If you provide a live demo http://jsfiddle.net I will show you.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Renderer works for me--thanks!--would you like to turn it into an answer so you can get the rep, or should I?

Answer (score 0):

You can add text by [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) or [labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels)